# Bundle issue due to the service provided in

Tags: php, symfony, service, bundle, symfony5

I've got a bundle with a service which is provided by this bundle. This service has differents paramaters (defined in `config/packages/pushTy.yaml`) which are included into the container thanks to the dependencyInjection.

However, sometimes I need to deactivate this bundle. For this, I edit `bundles.php` by deleting the line to declare the bundle. When I refresh my page, I got the following error:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "pushTy"

I don't understand why this error happens.

Comment: why can't you just adapt the line for the bundle in bundles.php, such that the value is [] instead of whatever you have there ... the error happens, because every config should have a purpose, if there's none, it's probably an error, that's why there's an error. ^^

Comment: Well, you mean by changing ['all' => true] to ['all' => false] ? Or ['all' => true] to []. In both case, the error is always present.

Comment: I believe this happens because the cached container (in `var/cache/__ENV__`) still refers to your now deleted bundle class. so, you can solve it by deleting the cache file - if you are in `prod` and `debug` is off, then, just manually delete the `KernelProdContainer.php` file. It will rebuild itself and you should be all set.

Comment: Because you still have  config file for the bundle in your app.  Symfony wants every config file to be processed and complains when it can't find one.  Changing the extension from yaml to yamlx should work.

Comment: @craigh Still not working, even if i delete the cache. I'm still in dev

Comment: @Cerad Would be a good idea, but what i'm currently doing is : With the admin panel, you can activate or desactivate a bundle. Changing the extension of the config file seems not be a good idea if i want to re-activate the bundle after that.

Comment: It's your call of course but you can't have one without other.  Just the way things work.  You could add a second fake MyBundle2 class and have it process the extension without doing anything.  You could then switch between the two bundle classes in bundles.php.  But I really think you should reconsider your design.